# why is this code returning true instead of false

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is the code :

```
const str = "asdfcvb";
const result = str.split("").every((e) => {
    return e==='a'||'b'});
console.log(result);
```

I expect str.split("") returns an array, and every method check if every element in the array equals to 'a' or 'b', which should return false, but it returns true

Comment: in return statement  in or operator 'b' part is always true, should be e ==='a' || e==='b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because
`e==='a'||'b'` means `((e==='a')||'b')`

When the `e !== 'a'` case, it will return `'b'` which is truthy in Javascript, so `every` method got truthy value from each term and then the result will be true.

You may use the follow to achieve what you want

```js
const result = str.split("").every((e) => {
    return (e==='a') || (e==='b')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't omit the `===` from the second part of your condition. Right now what you're saying is either return `e === 'a'` or `'b'`. When `e` is not equal to `'a'` it returns `'b'`. Which is truthy and when turned into a boolean it becomes true. Run this in the browser:

```
'a' === 'b' || 'c'
```

If you run it you see that it returns 'c'. The same happens in your callback. You have to change your return statement to this for it to work:

```
return e === 'a' || e === 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems correct.
The problem is in the way you compared the strings

you should compare those like `e === "a" || e === "b"`

and the working code

```js
const str = "asdfcvb";
const result = str.split("").every((e) => {
    return (e === "a" || e === "b")});
console.log(result);
```

Explanation:

`return e==='a'||'b'`

running the test for the first item which is `"a"` will return true as now `e` is `"a"` here, which is equal to `"a"`.

now if it gets to second item which is `"s"` and obviously not equal to `"a"` so `return e==='a'||'b'` becomes `return false||'b'` and now when you evaluate this the returned value will be `"b"`

and putting `"b"` as a condition is similar to `true` cause it is not `undefined` or `null`

this can be tested as follows

```js
if("b") return true; // returns true
```

Thus it returns `true` for every item thereby returning `true` at last

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `||` operator in your case incorrectly. This is a common typo. You are supposed to use the same equal to phrase after `||`. For example, your code would be like this:

```js
const str = 'asdfcvb';
const result = str.split('').every((e) => {
  return e === 'a' || e === 'b';
});

console.log(result);
```